# Apache Ignite: insert SQL with composite key via PreapredStatement

Tags: java, ignite

Say, I have a cache configured as `IgnateCache[CustomClass, SomePojo]`.
Here, `CustomClass` holds some number of primitives.

I want to insert in cache via thin JDBC driver and PreparedStatement.

1) What column name should I use in SQL to specify key? Is it `_key`?

2) How to set object of `CustomClass` to PreparedStatement? I've tried `PreparedStatement.setObject(int, Object)`, but got

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter type is unsupported. [cls=class
>   my.package.CustomClass]

at

> org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinPreparedStatement.setArgument(JdbcThinPreparedStatement.java:534)

Ignite version: 2.4.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should annotate your CustomClass with `@QuerySqlField` annotations on fields, refer to those fields individually in INSERT query by name.

Instead of annotations you can also use `QueryEntity`.

Comment: It's not possible to annotate CustomClass with @QuerySqlField cause it have @Target({ElementType.FIELD})

Comment: Did you mean to annotate not CustomClass itself, but its fields?

Comment: Yes! I'll clarify.